# fullcalendar eventMouseover rerenderEvents

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar fork with multiple resources.
I want to use callback "eventMouseover" to change border color for all events with the same title, I have something like that:

```
eventMouseover: function( event, jsEvent, view ) {
    //get day viewed
    var currentViewDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')

    var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', function(event) {
        //get list of events for displayed day
        if (moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == currentViewDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
            return true;    
        }
    });

    //search events with the same title as event where is mouse over
    for (var i = 0; events.length > i ; i++) {
        if (events[i].title == event.title) {
            events[i].borderColor = 'blue'
            console.log(event.title)
        }
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents')
}
```

and it works, means it changed border colors for particular events, but looks like when I put mouse over on event there is strange thing,
memory usage for browser is rapidly growing, CPU cons. about 50%.
Looks like it is constantly re rendering events.

As you can see from my code above I put

```
console.log(event.title)
```

to check how many times events with particular title will be displayed in console.

without

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents')
```

counting is correct every time when I put mouse pointer on event, but border colors is not changed,
but with

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents')
```

counting is incorrect, every time when mouse pointer is on event, counting in console constantly growing and CPU cons. is growing and memory as well,
but border is changed for all events with the same title in view.

Is there any workaround to execute

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents')
```

only one time when mouse is over event?
or maybe someone can help to do this in another way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that when you rerender the events, the eventMouseOver immediately triggered again, causing another rerender, and so on, until you keep the mouse on an event.

To prevent this, there are multiple solutions, e.g.: mark the event (add an attribute to it), and check this in your function, so when it is called again, you just skip. Of course this requires that when you mouseout, you unmark the event.

Another one is that you use a variable, if it is different than the current event title you mouseover-ed, save this new title and call the rerender. In the eventRender callback, check is the given event has the same title, if yes, change its border.